# dot-notation in Python using object

Tags: python-3.x

How does one do dot-notation easily? For example, when mocking the results of an `ArgumentParser`. I've started doing the following:

```
class ArbitraryObject:
    pass

foo = ArbitraryObject()
foo.dot = "dot notation works!"
foo.w00t = '!'
```

but I'd rather not make a custom class for this, since these end up littering my code everywhere. I would rather use `object` directly, but that results in this error:

```
>>> example_for_so = object()
>>> example_for_so.fail = "this should work, right?"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'fail'
>>>
```

So questions:

- Is there a simpler way to do this?
- Is using dot-notation like this generally frowned upon?

Edit for clarification:

Say the nominal code looks like this:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Example for S/O")
    parser.add_argument("filename", type=str, help="Output file")
    args = parser.parse_args()

    complicated_object = ComplicatedClass(args)
    complicated_object.calculate()
```

then I want a test that tests `ComplicatedClass`:

```
def test_using_attrdict():
    # Arrange
    input = attrdict.AttrDict({"filename": "sample_file.yml"})

    # Act
    complicated_object = ComplicatedClass(input)
    complicated_object.calculate()
```

or

```
def test_using_dot_notation():
    # Arrange
    input = ArbitraryObject()
    input.filename = "sample_file.yml"

    # Act
    complicated_object = ComplicatedClass(input)
    complicated_object.calculate()
```

Comment: Why not use a dictionary? This seems like exactly the kind of thing dictionaries are intended for. `a_dict["fail"] = "Some text"`

Comment: It doens't work when you use `object` because `object` instances don't have a `__dict__` attribute to store these attributes in.  New classes do have `__dict__`s unless you explicitly create them with `__slots__` instead.  Your questions asks "Is using dot-notation like this generally frowned upon?", but it's not clear what you're actually doing with these.

Comment: Thanks. I understand why it doesn't work when using `object()`, but rather i'm looking for a simpler way to do it. I've tried using `namedtuple`s but those come with the difficulty of being immutable